# msaccess find price at date

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to find a solution that works in MSAccess SQL (which is a little quirky)

I have a source table SalesPrices with data in the following form:

```
Product | Price | Time Effective
25      |  3.49 | 25/01/2013
25      |  3.65 | 02/02/2014
```

Now, what I want to do is for a given range of dates, produce a table of the price for a product and the week commencing date:

```
WC         | Product   | Price
13/01/2014 | 25        | 3.49
20/01/2014 | 25        | 3.49
27/01/2014 | 25        | 3.65
03/02/2014 | 25        | 3.65
```

So, to do this I have created a table of dates, with my desired date range

```
ID  | WC   
1   | 13/01/2014
2   | 20/01/2014
3   | 27/01/2014
4   | 3/02/2014
5   | 10/02/2014
```

I'm not entirely sure how to write the query though, it needs to produce a row for every product and every date in the tableofdates, with the price changing at the appropriate time

Something like a cross join of the tables, but I can't quite get the syntax

**EDIT to include my query so far**

```
SELECT [SalesPrices].[Product], [SalesPrices].[time eff], TableOfDates.WC, [SalesPrices].[Price]
FROM [SalesPrices], TableOfDates
WHERE ((([SalesPrices].[Product])=25) AND (([SalesPrices].[time eff]) 
Between [tableofdates].[wc] And ([tableofdates].[wc]+7)));
```

Comment: This would be much easier if you made a `WC` start date and a `WC` end date.  eg. start on 13/01/2014 end on 20/01/2014.  Then you could just left join where between those dates.

Comment: It's always 7 days, so I can join on the dates (between wc and wc+7). That doesn't give me all that I need though, just the weeks where the price changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a subquery:

```
select tod.wc, 25 as product,
       (select top 1 price
        from SalesPrices as sp
        where sp.TimeEffective <= tod.wc and product = 25
        order by TimeEffective desc, id
       ) as price
from TableOfDates as tod
where . . . <-- date conditions go here;
```

I'm not sure where the `25` comes from, so I just made it a fixed value in the query.

Comment: 25 is just an example of a product code, it comes from the SalesPrices table. This sql looks OK, but I am getting "At most one record can be returned by this subquery" in Access, despite the TOP 1 clause

Comment: @jazza1000 . . . Unlike in SQL Server, Access will include ties when using `top`.  So, you can get more rows than you ask for.  The solution is to include the unique id on each row.  I need to give credit where credit is due.  This site reminded me of this strange behavior:  http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-02.html.